# RewriteRule to point to subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

im trying to install phprojekt 6.0.4.
I see the directory structure doesnt allow to put the whole content into my public html folder and directly access it, as it has a htdocs folder in which normally my vhost docroot conf should point to.

So i want to change the .htaccess file in the root directory so every access to the root directory internally redirects to htdocs/ folder.

Im not able to get this running without 500 INTERNAL Errors.

I use these two lines to redirect.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule / htdocs/
```

So i whenever someone access the root folder of phprojekt, apache should point to htdocs/, it like trying to change the docroot from the root to the subfolder htdocs/.
How do i get this running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're not able to just change the DocumentRoot, try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !htdocs
RewriteRule (.*) htdocs/$1
```